# How to match one model to another

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I have two meshes. One is my design, the other a template for the second life head. I am needing to cut my designs head off, to equally match the template head neck's size and location.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT: I have a picture of the body that connects to the template head. This may make it better for those helping to understand what I am doing. I need my neck, to match up to the body. But I don't want them attached: https://gyazo.com/574ab3a66bccdabaa944962b251253d5**

This is a gif of the heads. Blue is template head and grey is my head/body.
https://gyazo.com/7abc394368acff87b771c37d7f95318a

Cheers,
CP

Comment: At final, you want to keep the head or the body?

Comment: I would like to keep the head at the end

Comment: I have gotten rid of the body so it's just the heads now. The orange Z frame is the one I want my neck to line up with, Just the bottom seams. I have marked the seams on both necks now. 
https://gyazo.com/8ea469b33611e8ce1c685a62714e663f

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it using the Properties tab and set the exact same properties. You can acces it by pressing N. You can also try to mess around with the snap thing located on top of the animation bar, it has a magnet icon.

Comment: I did have a look at this, however my neck seam has more verticies than the SL neck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating a circle with the same amount fo verts as the template mesh. I then joined that to my mesh and created a bridge before attaching the template and my mesh with Join, and merging the vertices and then removing the template mesh.